# Error on one of four drives, cannot format or read

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, hard-drive, partition

I'm having weird problems with a small SSD drive, F: (120GB).

```
C:\Users\Administrator>chkdsk f:
The type of the file system is RAW.
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.
```

Server management shows F: drive as healthy status, yet I was unable to create a text file in that drive in windows explorer plus getting errors shown above and in screenshots. Any idea how to rectify this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the drive intentionally formatted as RAW? Typically RAW FS are problematic within windows.

Comment: @robcalewar no not intentionally. My screenshots show that it won't let me even format it either

Comment: You may have to delete the volume and recreate it.